# ¿Alguna forma de optimizar este tipo de código?

Tags: c#, excel, optimización, spire

Estaba trabajando con hojas en excel y tengo que crear y eliminar varias de estas. 
El problema es que, haciéndolo como lo hago me queda un código bastante "*sucio*" a mi parecer y me preguntaba si hay alguna forma de hacerlo **más limpio.**

```
            //Añadimos una hoja auxiliar que guardamos en una variable auxiliar
        Worksheet aux = null;
        try
        {
            //Añado la hoja
            aux = workbook.Worksheets.Add("DATOS AUX");//Si existe lanza argumentException

        }
        catch (ArgumentException)
        {
            aux = workbook.Worksheets["DATOS AUX"];//Igualo Aux a la hoja que se llame "DATOS AUX"
            aux.Clear(); //La vacío por si contiene algún tipo de 
        }
        try
        {
            workbook.Worksheets.Add("Hoja1");//Añado hoja si existe lanza ARgumentException
        }
        catch (ArgumentException)
        {
            var hoja1= workbook.Worksheets["Hoja1"];//Igualo hoja1 a la hoja
            hoja1.Clear(); //la vacío 
        }
```

Uso `ArgumentException` ya que es la excepción que me da cuando esa hoja que intento crear ya existe y en la librería que uso no veo ningún metodo para hacer algo del tipo `if(Workbook.worksheet[indice].exists)...`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Puedes usar LINQ para comprobar si existe una hoja. Para ello debes hacer un paso previo, un cast de la colección `Worksheets` al tipo `Excel.Worksheet`, y ya posteriormente puedes comprobar si existe el nombre:

```
bool existe = workbook.Worksheets.OfType<Excel.Worksheet>().Select(x=>x.Name).Contains("DATOS AUX");
```

Si lo que quieres es que te devuelva la hoja si existe, o null en caso contrario, puedes usar `FirstOrDefault`:

```
var hoja = workbook.Worksheets.OfType<Excel.Worksheet>()
                              .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "DATOS AUX");
if (hoja == null)
{
    //no existe, la añadimos
    aux = workbook.Worksheets.Add("DATOS AUX");
}
else
{
    //existe, la asignamos en aux
    aux = hoja;
}
```

Si la hoja existe, te la devuelve en `hoja`, en caso contrario `hoja`será `null`.

**Edit**

Si no te permitieran usar Linq (hay gente muy rara), puedes crear un sencillo método:

```
private Excel.Worksheet ObtenerHoja(Workbook w, string nombre)
{
    foreach(Excel.Worksheet hoja in w.Worksheets)
    {
        if (hoja.Name == nombre)
        {
            return hoja;
        } 
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: ¿Esto sería únicamente para comprobar si existe la hoja, verdad?

Comment: Si, esto devuelve un booleano indicando si existe. Espera, te añado otra manera que te devuelva la hoja o null si no existe.

Comment: Gracias, funciona genial :)